# customized launcher in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

How do I debug customized launcher in android........
When ever i try to replace home screen  with my  login page app in launcher it show unfortunately stop.....
how can I debug and find where its stopping...
and where  I can add my code in customized launcher so it works properly,,,,,

```
07-05 12:31:25.896: E/filePathInTheme(16216): framework_res/res/mipmap-hdpi/sym_def_app_icon.png
07-05 12:31:25.956: E/filePathInTheme(16216): com.appaholics.launcher/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher_home.png
07-05 12:31:25.996: E/filePathInTheme(16216): com.appaholics.launcher/res/drawable-hdpi/images.png
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:848)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at com.appaholics.launcher.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:45)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at com.appaholics.launcher.Button_Clicker.onClick(Loginpage.java:107)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
07-05 12:31:32.966: E/AndroidRuntime(16216):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code that use internet in a separate thread or in a Async task.

As ICS and Jelly bean do not allow internet based process on main thread otherwise your app will give you **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**.

Check out this links below

[**Link-1**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

[**Link-2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Hope it will help you.